# How do I get two thread to insert specific timestamps into a table?

Tags: c#, database, multithreading, concurrency

I created two (or more) threads to insert data in a table in database. When inserting, there is a field `CreatedDateTime`, that of course, stores the datetime of the record creation.

For one case, I want the threads to stay synchronized, so that their `CreatedDateTime` field will have exactly the same value. When testing with multi threading, usually I've got different milliseconds...

I want to test different scenarios in my system, such as:

- 1) conflicts inserting record exactly at the same time.
- 2) problems with ordering/selection of records.
- 3) Problems with database connection pooling.
- 4) Problems with multiple users (hundred) accessing at same time.

There may be other test cases I haven't listed here.

Comment: This pretty much goes against the idea of having a thread scheduler...

Comment: I think you misunderstand the term synchronized.

Comment: I think the OP wants to generate a timestamp which can be shared between several threads? @Click OK: Maybe you should rephrase your question, and give an example of what you want to have.

Comment: Ok, I think your edit made it even more confusing...I'm out...

Comment: @ClickOK, I think I've made it a little clearer (come back, @divo, we miss you :-).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's what happens. Even if by some freak of nature, your threads were to start at exactly the same time, they would soon get out of step simply because of resource contention between them (at a bare minimum, access to the DB table or DBMS server process).

If they stay mostly in step (i.e., never more than a few milliseconds out), just choose a different "resolution" for your CreatedDateTime field. Put it in to the nearest 10<sup>th</sup> of a second (or second) rather than millisecond. Or use fixed values in some other way.

Otherwise, just realize that this is perfectly normal behavior.

And, as pointed out by BC in a comment, you may misunderstand the use of the word "synchronized". It's used (in Java, I hope C# is similar) to ensure two threads don't access the same resource at the same time. In actuality, it almost guarantees that threads won't stay synchronized as you understand the term to mean (personally I think your definition is right in terms of English usage (things happening at the same time) but certain computer languages have suborned the definition for their own purposes).

If you're testing what happens when specific timestamps go into the database, you cannot rely on threads "behaving themselves" by being scheduled in a specific order and at specific times. You really need to dummy up the data somehow, otherwise it's like trying to nail jelly to a tree (or training a cat).

One solution is to not use things such as `getCurrentTime()` or `now()` but use a specific set of inserts which have known timestamps. Depending on your actual architecture, this may be difficult (for example, if you just call an API which itself gets the current timestamp to millisecond resolution).

If you control the actual SQL that's populating the timestamp column, you need to change that to use pre-calculated values rather the `now()` or its equivalents.

Comment: But it doesn't answer the question how to generate an identical date-time value from different threads (or use the same timestamp in more than one thread safely).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the same timestamps on multiple rows being inserted; you should create a SQL thread which will do a multirow insert in one query which will allow you to get the same timestamps.  Other than this, I agree with everyone else, you cannot get an exact timestamp at a huge resolution with multithreads unless you were to insert the timestamp as it is seen in the application and share that timestamp to be inserted.  This of course, throws the caveat issues of threads out the window.  It's like saying, I'm going to share this data, but I don't want to use mutexes because they stop the other thread from processing once it hits a lock().